# org.hibernate.AnnotationException Mapping Error

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate

I'm triying to make a Shopping Cart with items. A user has multiple items, so I do this:
I have a @Entity @Table class Item, which implements Serializable

```
private User user;
```

...

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "items")
@Column(nullable = true, updatable = false)
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

and in User.java(@Entity @Table implements Serializable):

```
private List<Item> items; 
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

...

```
@ManyToOne
public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

what I got is this ERROR:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: org.auction.model.Item.user"}}
```

Comment: You've got your annotations backwards. `public List<Item> getItems()` is OneToMany and  `public User getUser()` is ManyToOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your annotation mixed up, @OneToMany is the one set for the collection

In Items class

```
 @ManyToOne(cascade = ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @Column(nullable = true, updatable = false)
  public User getUser() {
   return user;
  }
```

And in user class you will have OneToMany

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
public List<Item> getItems() {
   return items;
}
```

Comment: Done this.. also I've putted cascade, fetch and mappedBy "user" in OneToMany annotation.. I still get an ERROR: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Column(s) not allowed on a ManyToOne property: org.auction.model.Item.user
  Do you have any idea ?

Comment: actually the the mappedBy should be in the none owning entity, I will edit my answer accordingly